# How to emulate a javascript click event with curl or other tool?

Tags: javascript, events, click, command-line-interface, jitsi

I wrote my first React App using the @jitsi/react-sdk to mute all the participants in a Jitsi call. I need to do this via cli.

Besides my custom app, the question is more general. How to call any javascript click event pragmatically without human interaction via cli?

The button works perfectly but I need to be able simulate such click with curl or other means.

I didn't find any way to do it.

Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

You might give a try to [puppeterr](https://pptr.dev/) NodeJS library to simulate click event without human interaction.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const simulateClickEvent = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.goto('http://localhost:xxxx');
  
  await page.click('#myButton');
  
  await browser.close();
}
```

This code will launch headless browser instance and navigate to the specified URL. Then programmatically click the button with the ID of myButton. You can run this code from the command line using Node.js.